# How to convert a decimal larger than 255 into two of 8-bit (2 Bytes)

Tags: assembly, utf-8, numbers, byte, 8-bit

Ok I know how to convert decimal to `8-bit` for a example the char "A" by decimal it's `65`
It's very simple to convert it into binary
But what if the decimal is largen than `255`
Example the Arabic char `"م"` in decimal it is `1605` and in binary it is `11001000101`
When I convert it in any website it shows `11011001 10000101`
I want to know how `11001000101` be `11011001 10000101`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Arabic char "م" has code point 1605 in decimal. This is 0645h in hexadecimal and it is 0000'0110'0100'0101b in binary.

The utf-8 encoding will represent all characters with a code point in the range U+0000 to U+007F with 1 byte, using next template:

```
0_______
 ^
 | 7 bits
```

The utf-8 encoding will represent all characters with a code point in the range U+0080 to U+07FF with 2 bytes. Your Arabic char "م" is at U+0645h in this range.

When dealing with 2 bytes the template becomes

```
110_____ 10______
   ^       ^
   |       | 6 bits
   | 5 bits
```

In this template we fill in the lowest (only) 11 bits of the binary representation of your code point 11001'000101b:

```
110_____ 10______
   ^       ^
   | 11001 | 000101
```

This produces the binary 110'11001'10'000101b

Below is the x86 assembly version of the conversion for code points in [U+128, U+2047]:

```
                                       <------ AX ------->
mov ax, 1605        ; Your example:    0000 0110 0100 0101
                                        /                / 
                                       /                /  Shift left the whole 16 bits, twice
shl ax, 2                              0001 1001 0001 0100
                                                 \      \
                                                  \      \ Shift right the lowest 8 bits, twice
shr al, 2                              0001 1001 0000 0101
                                       |||       ||
                                       |||       ||        Put in the template bits
or  ax, 1100000010000000b              1101 1001 1000 0101
                                       <- AH --> <-- AL ->
```

Now the `AH` register contains the first byte of the utf-8 encoding and the `AL` register contains the second byte of the utf-8 encoding.

Because the x86 is a little endian architecture where the lowest byte is stored first in memory, an `xchg al, ah` instruction will fix the order of the bytes right before moving the result to memory:
`mov [somewhere], ax`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), in **Python** you can do something like this:

```
>>> "_".join(f"{byte:08b}" for byte in "م".encode("utf8"))
'11011001_10000101'
```